# change password char in HTML

Tags: html

can I change password char, in password-box in HTML. I want to change it to ■

Comment: Webkit browsers use the bullet symbol from the set font... here are instructions on how to change the [input password symbol](https://github.com/Mottie/input-password-bullet) using a custom font (webkit only).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As  far as I know, this can't be done. The password field is rendered natively by the browser.

You could probably build a JavaScript-based workaround, but that would not be as secure, break auto-completion and/or the browser's internal password management, and have other side-effects.

If at all possible, I would stick with the browser's rendering.

Comment: +1 - I've seen this attempted (never *done*) and it wasn't pretty

Comment: /agree with the "Stick with the standard behaviour, don't mess and break up things" way.

Comment: +1 for "stick with the browser's rendering." You don't even need expensive usability studies to determine that users are more comfortable with native UI elements than heavily-modified, non-standard controls.

Comment: @pekka is it still not possible in 2020

Answer (score 3):

That is controlled by the respective browser so as far as I know, it's not possible. You would have to come up with some out of the box solution but risking security, it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution availaible in javascript i have a function here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var k=0;
   var df;
window.onload=function() {
   df=document.forms[0];
df[1].onkeydown=function() {
    df[1].className='white';
 }
df[1].onkeyup=function() {
df[0].value+=df[1].value.charAt(k);
   k++;
for(c=0;c<df[1].value.length;c++) {
   df[1].value=df[1].value.replace(df[1].value.charAt(c),'#');
   df[1].className='black';
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```