# How to set passwordchar property to asp.net TextBox?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have one TextBox for Password and i want to set character for password, so which property can be used in asp.net?

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257053/change-password-char-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PasswordChar` property is under this namespace, System.Windows.Forms. It is not available for asp .net web applications.

You could try `JavaScript` to change it into other characters such as "*" or "@".

You can see the following example to do so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onTextChange(obj)
        {
            document.getElementById('hdnActualTextValue').value = obj.value;
            obj.value = '';
            for(int i=0; i<obj.value.length;i++)
            {
                obj.value +='*';//OR ANY OTHER CHARACTER OF YOUR CHOICE
            }
        }
        </script>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" onblur="javascript:onTextChange(this);"
            onkeyup="javascript:onTextChange(this);" onkeypress="javascript:onTextChange(this);"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnActualTextValue" runat="server" />
```

OR maybe you could use `input` in HTML.

```
<label>PW: <input type="password"></label>
```

Comment: @HarshitTailor I don't know why this is accepted as an answer. The JavaScript doesn't work (1. HiddenField wouldn't be found unless ClientIDMode was set to Static. 2. The for loop has invalid syntax and even if fixed, will never be entered). If it all were fixed to work as expected, the value of both the TextBox and the HiddenField would be empty on submission... considering the value is blanked out on keypress, keyup, and blur... and the `OR` option is simply how your original post will render as HTML....

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are using the Web Forms then in that the Password Characters are fixed. You can not change unless you use Javascript to change some behavior at run time

When we use WebForms in that PasswordCharacters are set by default.

Check out this [link](http://devssolution.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/set-watermark-text-when-textbox-mode-is-password/). You can get some Idea what I am telling you.

Comment: That is why I am telling you that the PasswordCharacters can not be set in Web Form. Because Password Fields gets the behavior according to the Browser in Web Forms...

Comment: No I think you can not set PasswordCharter directly to the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `TextMode` property in asp

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" TextMode ="Password"> </asp:TextBox>
```