# Get or set <input type="password"> masking character

Tags: html, unicode, cross-browser, cross-platform

Is there any cross-browser way of getting what the password masking character is in `<input type="password">` fields, or, barring that, to set it?

For example, Chrome & Firefox & Safari on OSX use [•](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm), while Safari on iOS 7 uses [●](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm). Perhaps other browsers might use the old-fashioned [*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a/index.htm) - I don't know.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this was asked previously as well. Check out [change password char in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257053/change-password-char-in-html) which states it can't be done.

Quick search shows that it can be done via JS by faking it and can't be done on a regular password field since it's defined by the browser. Refer to http://www.htmlforums.com/showpost.php?p=655392&postcount=4

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript">
   var k=0;
   var df;
window.onload=function() {
   df=document.forms[0];
df[1].onkeyup=function() {
df[0].value+=df[1].value.charAt(k);
   k++;
for(c=0;c<df[1].value.length;c++) {
   df[1].value=df[1].value.replace(df[1].value.charAt(c),'#');
   }
  }
 }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<noscript>
<div>
Without javascript enabled you will be unable to login
</div>
</noscript>

<form action="http://www.google.com/">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="password">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="submit password">
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so setting is out.. is there at least a way to retrieve what the character is, without changing it?

Comment: `df[1].onkeyup` should be `onkeydown`... otherwise, you'll see the character for a brief moment when you hit the key.

Comment: Hmm... actually, that code from htmlforums doesn't even seem to work properly for me... I tried writing my own, but I couldn't avoid leaving the typed character visible for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

this is a full implementation with styling and handling . i hope you like it :)

```js
function showHidePassword(passSelector, textSelector) {
    if ($(passSelector).hasClass("hidden")) {
        $(passSelector).val($(textSelector).val());
        $(textSelector).addClass("hidden");
        $(passSelector).toggleClass("hidden");
    }
    else {
        $(textSelector).val($(passSelector).val());
        $(passSelector).addClass("hidden");
        $(textSelector).toggleClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class='card'>
<div class='card-body'>
<div class='input-group'>
<div class='input-group-prepend'>
<span class='input-group-text'>
<i class='fa fa-key'></i>
</span>
</div>
<input type='password' id='password' class='form-control'/>
<input type='text' class='form-control hidden' id='passwordContent' disabled/>
<div class='input-group-append'><span class='input-group-text' onclick='showHidePassword("#password","#passwordContent")'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```