# Change the masking character in HTML5

Tags: html

How to change the masking character in HTML 5 of password field? Is it possible to do so?

I searched but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: post your code and scripts

Comment: You can always emulate the behaviour with Javascript.
I don't know how safe that would be though..

Comment: It's not natively supported to change that character. As @RubenSerrate says, it can be emulated, but I recommend against that. If you want to change it for you only, there are FF plugins that allow you to do so.

Comment: @RohitTiwari:I am new to HTML 5 and not sure whether we have some property to change it, as we have a function in java setChar('*') which changes the masking character accordingly. I have not written any script yet to do so, in searching phase yet. I would be thankful for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks all. I will search on your suggestions.

Comment: http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/89869.aspx hope this link would help to you

Comment: possible duplicate of [change password char in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257053/change-password-char-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do so by using a custom web font that uses another glyph for the asterisk character that browsers *usually* use to mask the input characters.

(If a browser were to use a different character, that won’t work then. But if you have a certain number of characters identified as *possible* masking characters, you could make a web font that uses the same glyph for all those characters.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.  The longer answer is to use what CBroe suggested and use a different font.

This actually turned out to be the solution to a wholly different problem that I had.  I was noticing in my password boxes that the box was "jumping" by a couple of pixels whenever the user typed in their PIN.  I thought this was just an IE 10/11 problem but it turned out to be the *font* of all things.  I was using the Lato font:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and for whatever reason, the password bullet being used was causing the input box to move.  The solution ended up being to simple change the font of the password input box to pretty much ANYTHING else, and the jumping stopped.

```
#choose_pin,
#confirm_pin
{
    width: 188px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```