# Mask password character size too small

Tags: html, css

Compared to Firefox, Chrome mask password character is a little bit too small.

[image: Firefox]

This one is from Firefox, and below if from Chrome

[image]

What CSS fix would fix this issue, that the same big mask size to be applied for Chrome?

Comment: I think there have been a few questions asked like this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257053/change-password-char-in-html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to use a media query that will only match for Chrome (or other WebKit based browsers):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

}
```

And to increase the size of those dots you can use `-webkit-text-stroke-width` in combination with `letter-spacing`:

```
/* this will only apply to Webkit browsers like Chrome */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type="password"] {
       -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.2em;
       letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5au4pgn/)

Comment: What is needed is that the placeholder text to remain normal just the mask to be adjusted

Comment: this is not the requirement.